# Bitcoin full node installation on Raspberry Pi3 not working

Tags: bitcoin-core, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to setup a Bitcoin full node including GUI & wallet based on guide on raspnode.com but I got stuck at the this point:

'i@raspnode~/bin/bitcoin$ make -j2'

having this error:

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/bin/bitcoin/src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/bin/bitcoin/src'
  CXX      bitcoind-bitcoind.o
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/bin/bitcoin/src/secp256k1'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/bin/bitcoin/src/secp256k1'
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-chain.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-checkpoints.o
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:24:0,
             from scheduler.h:15,
             from bitcoind.cpp:15:
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:3188:0: error: unterminated #if
 #if ! defined BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES
 ^
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:3164:0: error: unterminated #if
 #if defined BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CTOR_ALLOCATORS
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:24:0,
             from scheduler.h:15,
             from bitcoind.cpp:15:
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:16:0: error: unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS
 ^
/usr/include/boost/thread/future.hpp:8:0: error: unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE_HPP
 ^
In file included from util.h:18:0,
             from bitcoind.cpp:16:
tinyformat.h:104:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘namespace’
 namespace tinyformat {}
 ^ 
tinyformat.h:109:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘namespace’
 namespace tfm = tinyformat;
 ^
In file included from util.h:18:0,
             from bitcoind.cpp:16:
tinyformat.h:150:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘namespace’
 namespace tinyformat {
 ^
bitcoind.cpp:191:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 }
 ^
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:15:0:
scheduler.h:80:87: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
     bool shouldStop() { return stopRequested || (stopWhenEmpty && taskQueue.empty()); }
                                                                                   ^
scheduler.h:80:87: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
Makefile:7351: recipe for target 'bitcoind-bitcoind.o' failed
make[2]: *** [bitcoind-bitcoind.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/bin/bitcoin/src'
Makefile:8357: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/bin/bitcoin/src'
Makefile:668: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like libboost is not installed?

Try:

`apt install libboost-all-dev -y`

Then rebuild:

`./autogen.sh; ./configure; make`

Answer (score 0):

What Config option are you using? I'm assuming you're using [this](http://raspnode.com/diyBitcoin.html#installbitcoin) guide from the mentioned domain. If so you've three options for the `./configure` stage of install because you've mentioned full and GUI I've pulled the needed Config line out

```
 ./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/include -O2" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib" --enable-upnp-default --with-gui
```

Note those file paths may need adjusted of you've installed dependencies elsewhere.

If you're still having errors it would be helpful to know what commands you've entered leading up to the posted build errors.

### edits and updates

Looking real close at the error logs posted there seems to be an `'` or `"` or similar that didn't get *closed* it starts showing up at a `if` statements not being terminated correctly near the top of the log. Additionally if your copy/pasting commands from a web page into your terminal the quotation and other special characters maybe not interpreted correctly. Definitely start the guide from the top by manually typing in commands if that sounds correct because those errors are usually caused by something being misstyped or misinterpreted.

Comment: Building with `-j4` will certainly cause an out of memory. An RPi3 doesn't nearly have enough memory to run 4 gcc's in parallel.

Comment: Ah go call, last I'd built my node was on similarly limited hardware but I've yet to have the drive space to try again on the RPi without bootstrapping. I'll remove the bad suggestion, thank you Pieter.